# How can I programmatically remove Sidebar and Header in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, apexpage

I am aware of the `<apex:page>` attributes for `sidebar="false"` and `showHeader="false"` but is it possible to determine these within the page logic (either Visualforce, legitimate Javascript on page, or part of an Apex controller/action method)?

Basically, I have a Visualforce which already has some logic to determine what to show in it's main body, and in some instances, I want this to be full screen, removing the sidebar and headers, in other cases, I simply want the page to remain in the "standard" frame for the user.

Incidentally, I'm not interested in crazy Javascript hacks to target `window.window.document.getElementById[..]` or unsupported CSS tricks to just `display:none;` the relevant sections; everything I do is best practice, supported and by the book!

My current only thinking is to instead re-direct the user to a new page with those attributes set and move my "full page" experience to there. This is slightly poorer from a maintenance point of view though, and will result in double the VF pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind these attributes to controller properties. It might get a little wonky if you try to re-render, but assuming you know the values at load time, the following binding ought to work:

```
<apex:page sidebar="{!showSidebar}" showHeader="{!showHeader}">
    <!-- intermediate markup -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This does work a treat,  I can determine and populate the instance variables in apex in the controller extension and it drives the properties perfectly. It's so simple, it's perfect, no idea why I didn't think I could merge them in.